# @each loop inside of a @include argument

Tags: css, sass, scss-mixins

I'm trying to loop inside of a loop so as to cross all colors and their selector within a list with every other color and selector within the same list.

Currently things look like this. But this requires me manually adding each variation to cross against, not what I want.

```
$rgbaList: "trn" transparent, "lt" rgba($lt, 0.9999), "dk" rgba($dk, 0.9999),
  "lt-grey" rgba($lt-grey, 0.9999), "p1" rgba($p1, 0.9999),
  "p2" rgba($p2, 0.9999), "p3" rgba($p3, 0.9999), "s1" rgba($s1, 0.9999),
  "s2" rgba($s2, 0.9999), "s3" rgba($s3, 0.9999), "s4" rgba($s4, 0.9999);

%curve {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 4vw;
  bottom: -2vw;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 101;
  width: 100%;
}
@mixin curve($c1, $c2) {
  &::after {
    @extend %curve;
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg width='100%' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' x='0px' y='0px' viewBox='0 0 400 10' preserveAspectRatio='none' style='width:100%;' xml:space='preserve'%3E%3Cpath fill='#{$c1}' d='M0,0v10c0,0,81.6-5,200-5s200,5,200,5V0H0z'/%3E%3Cpath fill='#{$c2}' d='M0,10c0,0,81.6-5,200-5s200,5,200,5H0z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E%0A");
  }
}
@each $i in $rgbaList {
//Dont want to have to manually add each variant inside 
//this @each (tried using @each within @each - shown below). 
  .curve-#{nth($i, 1)}-trn {
    @include curve(#{nth($i, 2)}, transparent);
  }
  .curve-#{nth($i, 1)}-lt {
    @include curve(#{nth($i, 2)}, rgba($lt, 0.9999));
  }
  .curve-#{nth($i, 1)}-dk {
    @include curve(#{nth($i, 2)}, rgba($dk, 0.9999));
  }
  .curve-#{nth($i, 1)}-lt-grey {
    @include curve(#{nth($i, 2)}, rgba($lt-grey, 0.9999));
  }
// and so on
```

I've attempted something along the lines of the below using @each in place of the selector and argument but @each used in this way doesn't work:

```
@each $i in $rgbaList {
  .curve-#{nth($i, 1)}-/*each > $i1 here*/ {
    @extend .curve;
    @include curve(#{nth($i, 2)}, /*each > $i2 here*/);
  }
}
```

How else can I approach this?

The expected result when half-manually(if that were a thing) coded myself like at the start, looks like the below:

```
.curve-trn-trn::after,
.curve-trn-lt::after,
.curve-trn-dk::after,
.curve-trn-lt-grey::after,
.curve-trn-p1::after,
.curve-trn-p2::after,
.curve-trn-p3::after,
.curve-trn-s1::after,
.curve-trn-s2::after,
.curve-trn-s3::after,
.curve-trn-s4::after,
.curve-lt-trn::after,
.curve-lt-lt::after,
.curve-lt-dk::after,
.curve-lt-lt-grey::after,
.curve-lt-p1::after,
.curve-lt-p2::after,
.curve-lt-p3::after,
.curve-lt-s1::after,
.curve-lt-s2::after,
.curve-lt-s3::after,
.curve-lt-s4::after,
.curve-dk-trn::after,
.curve-dk-lt::after,
.curve-dk-dk::after,
.curve-dk-lt-grey::after,
.curve-dk-p1::after,
.curve-dk-p2::after,
.curve-dk-p3::after,
.curve-dk-s1::after,
.curve-dk-s2::after,
.curve-dk-s3::after,
.curve-dk-s4::after,
.curve-lt-grey-trn::after,
.curve-lt-grey-lt::after,
.curve-lt-grey-dk::after,
.curve-lt-grey-lt-grey::after,
.curve-lt-grey-p1::after,
.curve-lt-grey-p2::after,
.curve-lt-grey-p3::after,
.curve-lt-grey-s1::after,
.curve-lt-grey-s2::after,
.curve-lt-grey-s3::after,
.curve-lt-grey-s4::after,
//AND SO ON
{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 4vw;
  bottom: -2vw;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 101;
  width: 100%;
}
.curve-trn-trn::after {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg width='100%' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' x='0px' y='0px' viewBox='0 0 400 10' preserveAspectRatio='none' style='width:100%;' xml:space='preserve'%3E%3Cpath fill='rgba(0,0,0,0)' d='M0,0v10c0,0,81.6-5,200-5s200,5,200,5V0H0z'/%3E%3Cpath fill='rgba(0,0,0,0)' d='M0,10c0,0,81.6-5,200-5s200,5,200,5H0z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E%0A");
}
.curve-trn-lt::after {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg width='100%' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' x='0px' y='0px' viewBox='0 0 400 10' preserveAspectRatio='none' style='width:100%;' xml:space='preserve'%3E%3Cpath fill='rgba(0,0,0,0)' d='M0,0v10c0,0,81.6-5,200-5s200,5,200,5V0H0z'/%3E%3Cpath fill='rgba(247,247,247,0.9999)' d='M0,10c0,0,81.6-5,200-5s200,5,200,5H0z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E%0A");
}
.curve-trn-dk::after {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg width='100%' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' x='0px' y='0px' viewBox='0 0 400 10' preserveAspectRatio='none' style='width:100%;' xml:space='preserve'%3E%3Cpath fill='rgba(0,0,0,0)' d='M0,0v10c0,0,81.6-5,200-5s200,5,200,5V0H0z'/%3E%3Cpath fill='rgba(42,42,42,0.9999)' d='M0,10c0,0,81.6-5,200-5s200,5,200,5H0z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E%0A");
}
.curve-trn-lt-grey::after {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg width='100%' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' x='0px' y='0px' viewBox='0 0 400 10' preserveAspectRatio='none' style='width:100%;' xml:space='preserve'%3E%3Cpath fill='rgba(0,0,0,0)' d='M0,0v10c0,0,81.6-5,200-5s200,5,200,5V0H0z'/%3E%3Cpath fill='rgba(235,235,236,0.9999)' d='M0,10c0,0,81.6-5,200-5s200,5,200,5H0z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E%0A");
}
//AND SO ON
```

Comment: Can you show what is the expected result? And what is inside the `curve` mixin?

Comment: @Arkellys I've updated the post

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the colour variables you want to be repeated into another list and then loop over that list inside of your original loop. I have provided a sassmeister sandbox illustrating what I mean.

```
$colours: $lt, $dk, $lt-grey; //... and so on

@each $i in $rgbaList {
  .curve-#{nth($i, 1)} {
    @extend %curve;
    @each $colour in $colours {
      @include curve(#{$colour}, #{nth($i, 2)});
    }
  }
}
```

Here is a sassmeister sandbox example. https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/20ed2ad09e29b7fb1ddff8b87ff3c8ba

Comment: No I need another loop within each iteration of the first loop so that any single iteration of the first loop produces mulitple classes of one color varation along with all other colors

Comment: Gotcha, I have updated sassmeister and my answer. I hope this helps.